# How to use custom cell renderer in custom control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have custom Layout and custom cell renderer for each platform.

**Custom cell:**

```
public class NativeCell : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Title), typeof(string), typeof(MenuItemNativeCell), "");

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Simple UWP Renderer:

```
public class NativeCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    public override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetTemplate(Cell cell)
    {
        return App.Current.Resources["MenuItemTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

DataTemplate in UWP Project:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Margin="5">
        <Grid Margin="3"
              Padding="20"
              Background="Black">
            <Image Source="{Binding Title, Converter={StaticResource ImagePlaceholderConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When a cell is created in custom layout, the **viewCell.View** is null.

```
    private ViewCell CreateViewCell(object item)
    {
        ViewCell viewCell;

        if (ItemTemplate is DataTemplateSelector templateSelector)
        {
            var template = templateSelector.SelectTemplate(item, null);
            viewCell = template.CreateContent() as ViewCell;
        }
        else
        {
            viewCell = ItemTemplate.CreateContent() as ViewCell;
        }

        viewCell.View.BindingContext = item;

        return viewCell;
    }
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Custom layout is written in xamarin.forms without renderer.
You can see the layout source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom)

**UPD**:
Using breakpoints, I found that the function GetTemplate in renderer is not called. I tried to replace ViewCell With NativeCell, but its not worked.

Comment: Did you register the renderer in the proper way? I.e.: `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeCell), typeof(NativeCellRenderer))]`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis yes, of courses. For example, it works with ListView control. I think, that my custom control without renderers and it’s problem. I will try to rewrite the custom control and using a ListView.